Can you delete a chart using the chart ID
I have a spreadsheet with approximately 100 sheets and some sheets have 40-50 embedded charts. When I either delete a specific chart or modify it I have to search all charts on a sheet until I can uniquely identify it (either by title or by anchor cell - row and column). This is a slow process, especially as charts are added.
When I create a chart I can retrieve and store a chart ID. Is there a way I can use this ID to directly identify a chart to delete or modify and so avoid the serial search? Also, if there is another way without using the ID which can avoid this serial search please point in that direction as well.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, about Can you delete a chart using the chart ID, I think that it's yes. In this case, when the Sheets API is used, the charts can be deleted using the chart IDs. Also, when Sheets API is used, all charts including the chart IDs can be retrieved by one API call. But, if these were not included in your expected result, I apologize.

If you have its ID, you can delete a chart using Class EmbeddedChart and Sheet.removeChart as follows:
function deleteChart(id, sheetName) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const chart = sheet.getCharts().find(chart => chart.getChartId() === +id);
  if (!chart) {
    throw new Error('Chart not found.');
  } else {
    sheet.removeChart(chart);
  }
}

You can also delete a chart using its title as follows:
function deleteChart(title, sheetName) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const chart = sheet.getCharts().find(chart => chart.getOptions().get('title') === title);
  if (!chart) {
    throw new Error('Chart not found.');
  } else {
    sheet.removeChart(chart);
  }
}

Alternatively, if you have its anchor cell, you can delete it as follows:
function deleteChart(anchorCell, sheetName) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const row = sheet.getRange(anchorCell).getRow();
  const col = sheet.getRange(anchorCell).getColumn();
  const chart = sheet.getCharts().find(chart => {
    const container = chart.getContainerInfo();
    return container.getAnchorRow() === row &&
           container.getAnchorColumn() === col
  });
  if (!chart) {
    throw new Error('Chart not found.');
  } else {
    sheet.removeChart(chart);
  }
}

References

Sheet.getCharts
Sheet.removeChart
EmbeddedChart
ChartOptions
ContainerInfo


Instead of adding a meta-commentary, use the Edit Summary to describe what was changed

Thanks. I will try the code in your first snippet. I have previously tried similar code to the other 2 but found it was very slow and clearly became slower as more charts needed to be searched.

The technique you gave using the chart ID was the best solution for my problem as there were some charts with the same title and sometimes users moved charts.

Glad I could help :) If it solved your issue, know that you can accept the answer so other members of the community may know it worked.
